# Как зайти на FTP если он без пароля?

Tags: ftp

Есть FTP, на который можно зайти без пароля через браузер: просто по ссылке. Как можно зайти на него через FileZilla или любой другой клиент?

Мне пишет, что логин «anonymous» не подходит, но через Chrome вхожу по ссылке без проблем.

Comment: Дайте ссылку ... Что за ОС?

Comment: На Ubuntu 14.04 LTS в FileZilla 3.7.3 всё исправно работает: **1)** вставляю ссылку (ftp://mirror.yandex.ru); **2)** нажимаю «Quick connect»; **3)** в поле «Username» автоматически подставляется «anonymous» и соединение устанавливается. http://i.stack.imgur.com/LCE24.png

Comment: Скажите ему в качестве пароля anonymous хоть что-нибудь. В принципе подходит любая строка, но часто рекомендуют адрес почты. Может какие-то сервера проверяют пароль anonymous-а на соответствие шаблону почтового адреса?